# laravel mongodb Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: laravel, mongodb

I have an error when I want to save data.

The error occurs only on the **VPS server**,
when i run it on **localhost**, it works fine.

my script:

```
$rating = new \willvincent\Rateable\Rating;
$rating->rating = $request->rate;
$rating->rateable_id = $request->id;
$rating->rateable_type = 'App\Product';
$rating->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
$rating->title = $request->title;
$rating->detail = $request->detail;
$rating->save();
```

All data is filled in properly, only when entering the `$rating->save();` process does an error occur.

error message:

```
"message": "Call to a member function prepare() on null",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError",
"file": "/home/krabs/public_html/pricesm.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
"line": 452,
```

**Problem was Fix:**

- the problem is with my VPS server configuration

Comment: Where is your `$post` ??

Comment: Maybe related to [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/1526) issue?

Comment: @A.ANoman The error hasn't arrived at `$post`

Comment: @Tpojka I think it has no effect, because on `localhost` I am running well.